# Destroy a record before it's saved in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my model I have specified a before_save method to run, and check the new record against some data. If the new record isn't what I want - how can I stop it from being saved?

Here is essentially what I'm trying to do (and failing):

```
before_save :itemCheck

  def itemCheck
    if self.item_type_id == 1
        if self.num > 6
          self.destroy
        end
    end 
  end
```

NOTE: my code is more complicated than this - just making a simple example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return `false` from your `before_save` and the record won't be saved.

As a sidenote: don't use camelcase for functions, but use: `item_check`.

Comment: I am curious - why shouldn't I use camelcase for functions?

Comment: @Elliot The Ruby convention is to use `Upper::CamelCase` for class and module names, `snake_case` for variable and method names and UPPER_CASE for constants